# CKAN Theming: how to remove the bottom block under footer?

Tags: ckan

I am working on changing the theme of CKAN webpage. After I edited the color of footer (footer.html), I found that there was another block under the footer. Screenshot is shown below:
[image: CKAN footer and bottom block]

(I changed the color of footer to lighter grey, but the teal block is still there)

The problem is that I can't remove this bottom block and I can't find the right .html or .css file that defines this block.I have tried to edit footer.html, page.html, and base.html in my theme extension but I still can't get rid of this bottom block.

Anyone knows how to deal with this problem? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some good instructions here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/css.html